# No ESLint configuration found for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, reactjs, eslint

I have installed the ESLint plugin for Visual Studio Code editor and it shows that it is installed also but still I see the error: **No ESLint configuration found for Visual Studio Code** at the top of the editor window as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me to know is there anything that I am missing here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are missing **.eslintrc.*** file. Which can be in different format js, json, yaml... There are two available methods to create configuration file

- Manually, just create file and add rules
- use init command `$ ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init` or `eslint --init` if you have ESLint installed globally. Then follow instructions and after edit created file to your liking.

  More info:
- http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring
- https://github.com/eslint/eslint

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but still I see a underline under the word import.It shows a warning: Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType:module'. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: you need to add `"sourceType": "module"` to your eslint config, under parserOptions, by default sourceType is "script"

`{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    }
}`

[More info](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options)

Comment: The above setting fixed it but now I see one new error: 'React' is defined but never used.(no-unused-vars). I tried to set "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "vars": "all", "args": "after-used" }] but still the error persists.

Comment: `$ npm install eslint-plugin-react -D` and add `{
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ]
}` to config

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. All the issues are resolve now :)